# SQL Database in restoring mode

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-backups, database-restore

We have a database that we were doing a backup for, it has a TL of 550GB, I don't know why and how but it went in restoring mode.

Its been a couple of days now and its still in restoring mode. What are my options to fix this?

What does take offline do?

I just want it back in the same state that it was in..

Thanks

Comment: I'd recommend transferring this question to http://dba.stackexchange.com.  The DBAs there are much more likely to know the best way to handle this.

Comment: It *sounds* like SQL Server, but yes, @Sarah should clarify which DBMS it is.

Comment: I strongly suspect that you will need to do a `RESTORE DATABASE WITH RECOVERY` at some point, but there may be other steps you need to do first to insure that you do not lose any data.

Comment: Sorry guys, I didn't make myself clear. I am talking about MS SQL 2015 here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Take offline" disconnects it from SQL Server. You can try it, however if it thinks it's stuck in a restore, you probably won't be able to take it offline.

After (if) "take offline" finishes, it will say "offline" and you can then select "Bring online" from the right click menu and bring it back online.

I hope you have good backups besides the one it just tried to do. You may end up needing to do an actual restore if it's really hosed.

Comment: Yes, that is what we ended up doing actually, but lost all the TL to eventually find out what happened that took it to that state.

Comment: @Sarah if you can't afford to lose data, you might want to talk to someone about setting up read-only replication or some other kind of fault-tolerant system. SQL Server is very reliable, but it does fail now and then, whether from hardware or software or cosmic rays or whatever. I'd assume this will happen again and make sure you can handle the failure.